# Не работает Ajax: отсутствует подключение

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Несмотря на долгие часы гугления, Ajax не подключается ни в какую. Я упростил код до максимума.

Это - основной файл `index.php`. Jquery, как видите, подключил:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    ...

    <!--js-->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateLayout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo 'TestResult '. $_POST['testData'];
?>

</body>
```

Сам Ajax-запрос находится во внешнем файле (директория `js/`):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'index.php',
  data: 'testData=test'
});
```

Я использую NetBeans в сочетании с OpenServer, адрес целевой страницы; отображающийся в браузере - `http://testproject/index.php`. Допускаю, что может быть не так прописал адрес в запросе; пробовал и `http://testproject/index.php`, и `testproject/index.php`, но ничего не меняется.

Что ещё стоит попробовать?

Comment: Ответ пользователя Lakremon не верный. Почему вы отметили его, как решение?

Comment: Я сам ошибся, приняв ответ за правильный; прошу прощения. (следствие 9 часов работы, половину которых - поиск ответа на данный вопрос).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На момент, когда рендерится файл index.php POST данных не существует. 
В вашем случае они появляются только после того, как был сформирован html ответ, передан уже клиенту(в браузер), и только потом были отправлены данные POST.

Естественно для их отображения уже поздновато. Не забывайте, что JavaScript исполняется уже на стороне клиента, в отличие от PHP.

Пожалуйста попробуйте понять и протестировать следующий код:

файл `index.php`

```
<?php
// Проверяем, есть ли POST данные "testData"
if(isset($_POST['testData'])){
    echo "Ура, данные 'testData' пришли: ".$_POST['testData']."";
    exit();
}
?>

    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p id='postData'>POST данных не обнаружено</p>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value ="Отправить testData">
    </body>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CreateLayout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </html>
```

файл `CreateLayout.js`

```
// При клике отправляем post данные
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'testData=test',
      success: function(data){
          // В случае успешного ответа сервера вставляем ответ сервера в тег <p>
          $("#postData").text(data);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Хорошо, всё работает. Спасибо Вам большое за конструктивный ответ с объяснением и ещё раз прошу прощения за ошибку в выборе победителя.

Comment: Всегда рад помочь. Спасибо и Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/index.php',
  data: {
      testData:"test"
  }
});
```

Comment: А, нет, к сожалению я ошибся. Ваше решение тоже не работает.